# What ways to make data accessible via mobile borwser?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, mobile-website, azure-storage

I have built a website with asp.net/c# ,jquery,SQL Server 2008.

The website and data are hosted inside a hosting company.

I want to build a mobile version of the website.how can i make the data(that are now in SQL Server 2008)  accessible for mobile?

Should i migrate the data to a cloud such as Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Well a mobile phone accesses the web just like a PC just with a smaller screen and different browser (at times), so making a different theme for your website that would show only for mobile devices would be sufficient, unless you are talking about a downloadable app that runs on the device itself and not in the browser.

If it's browser based. Use this to make it work better with mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

Comment: thank you brenjt.so i don't have to migrate data to anywhere.i can access them as they are from mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple versions of a website in one host. Some sites use [media queries](http://www.broken-links.com/2011/02/21/using-media-queries-in-the-real-world/) to create two different presentations of the same website. This is a good, simple way to do things but it will not be the best experience for mobile users. It's very hard to create content that is equally useful for mobile and desktop browsers.

Another approach is to create a second copy of your site with a theme and navigation optimized for mobile. For example, your site may look for the string "mobile" in the user agent string and send the user to m.yoursite.com. This gives you a better chance of optimizing content for mobile users. Hosting sites commonly give you the ability to host multiple domains off one account.

If you'd prefer to make a native app (I don't recommend this) then you'd want to expose your APIs so that a native version can query your API to get the data it needs.